# What are the reasons for running a full node on a VPS? How can I do this?

Tags: full-node, nodes, global-node-distribution

I've seen some people say they run full nodes on a VPS. What are the reasons for doing this and how might I do it too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are the reasons for doing this

First, a full node hosted on a VPS ensures high uptime. If you run a node on a personal computer, you will likely only run it partially, because you turn your computer off from time to time. Higher uptime is better for the network. However, ideally, such a node would run off a personal computer instead of a VPS. There's always an aspect of centralization with respect to VPS providers which people have to keep in mind when making such a decision.

Additionally, people might find it more convenient to run their node on a VPS.

---

> and how might I do it too?

There's a [guide](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/user-guides/vps_run_node) on the official website:

> ## monerod
>
> `monerod` is the daemon software that ships with the Monero tree. It is a console program, and manages the blockchain. While a bitcoin wallet manages both an account and the blockchain, Monero separates these: `monerod` handles the blockchain, and `simplewallet` handles the account.
>
> This guide assumes you have already set up your VPS account and are using SSH to tunnel into the server console.
>
> ### Linux, 64-bit (Ubuntu 14.04)
>
> #### Make sure that port 18080 is open
>
> `monerod` uses this port to communicate with other nodes on the Monero network.
>
> Example if using `ufw`: `sudo ufw allow 18080`
>
> Example if using `iptables`: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 18080 -j ACCEPT`
>
> #### Download the current Monero Core binaries
>
> `wget https://downloads.getmonero.org/linux64`
>
> #### Make a directory and extract the files.
>
> `mkdir monero`
>      `tar -xjvf linux64 -C monero`
>
> #### Launch the daemon
>
> `cd monero`
>      `./monerod`
>
> #### Options:
>
> Show list of all options and settings:
>
> `./monerod --help`
>
> Launch the daemon as a background process:
>
> `./monerod --detach`
>
> Monitor the output of `monerod` if running as daemon:
>
> `tail -f ~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the issues of uptime and convenience that dEBRUYNE mentioned, another reason for running a node on a VPS could be that you want to run a service that utilizes a Monero wallet, but you don't have the infrastructure to support a wallet processing a lot of transactions, then you can use a VPS to scale the hardware and bandwidth as needed.